# Sqlite3 Locking Database on a read

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to lock a database on a read (for research on malicious purposes). I am aware that Sqlite3 locks a database (file) on writes but I'm not familiar with how to do so with a read. Is this possible to lock a database until the DB is restarted/manually reset?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but the problem sounds less like a database constraint and more like a general file constraint.  Access is usually defined by the UAM policy (mode, user, group etc), so I'd suggest approaching this problem from that lens, instead of a database lens.  You could change file mode before and after you use it to "lock" and "unlock" it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, SQLite by default locks the entire file when inserting into the "database" so that nobody can read/write. I was wondering if it was possible to artificially create a race condition with nested reads in order to create a locking race condition with reads